# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

I've used the Hibernate Reverse engineering to create my models along with its mapping and relationships. However when I try to do a simple select, an error is shown. I don't know what's wrong with my mapping. Here is the code of two models. The Student Model is the parent and Assessment model is child.

The Assessment Model:

```
            import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
    import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Temporal;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

    /**
     * Assessment generated by hbm2java
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Assessment", catalog = "mydb")
    public class AssessmentModel implements java.io.Serializable {

        private AssessmentIdModel id;
        private SpEdTeacherModel spedteacher;
        private StudentModel Student;
        private Date assessmentDate;
        private Set<IepModel> ieps = new HashSet<IepModel>(0);
        private Set<SkillassessmentModel> skillassessments = new HashSet<SkillassessmentModel>(0);

        public AssessmentModel() {
        }

        public AssessmentModel(AssessmentIdModel id, SpEdTeacherModel spedteacher, StudentModel Student, Date assessmentDate) {
            this.id = id;
            this.spedteacher = spedteacher;
            this.Student = Student;
            this.assessmentDate = assessmentDate;
        }

        public AssessmentModel(AssessmentIdModel id, SpEdTeacherModel spedteacher, StudentModel Student, Date assessmentDate, Set<IepModel> ieps,
                Set<SkillassessmentModel> skillassessments) {
            this.id = id;
            this.spedteacher = spedteacher;
            this.Student = Student;
            this.assessmentDate = assessmentDate;
            this.ieps = ieps;
            this.skillassessments = skillassessments;
        }

        @EmbeddedId

        @AttributeOverrides({
                @AttributeOverride(name = "assessmentId", column = @Column(name = "assessment_id", nullable = false) ),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "spedId", column = @Column(name = "sped_id", nullable = false) ),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "studentId", column = @Column(name = "student_id", nullable = false) ) })
        public AssessmentIdModel getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(AssessmentIdModel id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "sped_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
        public SpEdTeacherModel getSpedteacher() {
            return this.spedteacher;
        }

        public void setSpedteacher(SpEdTeacherModel spedteacher) {
            this.spedteacher = spedteacher;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
        public StudentModel getStudent() {
            return this.Student;
        }

        public void setStudent(StudentModel Student) {
            this.Student = Student;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name = "assessment_date", nullable = false, length = 10)
        public Date getAssessmentDate() {
            return this.assessmentDate;
        }

        public void setAssessmentDate(Date assessmentDate) {
            this.assessmentDate = assessmentDate;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Assessment")
        public Set<IepModel> getIeps() {
            return this.ieps;
        }

        public void setIeps(Set<IepModel> ieps) {
            this.ieps = ieps;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Assessment")
        public Set<SkillassessmentModel> getSkillassessments() {
            return this.skillassessments;
        }

        public void setSkillassessments(Set<SkillassessmentModel> skillassessments) {
            this.skillassessments = skillassessments;
        }

    }
```

Student Model:

```
        import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Temporal;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

    /**
     * Student generated by hbm2java
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Student", catalog = "mydb")
    public class StudentModel implements java.io.Serializable {

        private Integer studentId;
        private GuardianModel guardian;
        private String studentFname;
        private String studentMname;
        private String studentLname;
        private Date studentBirthdate;
        private int studentAge;
        private String studentGender;
        private String studentNationality;
        private String studentProgram;
        private Set<AssessmentModel> assessments = new HashSet<AssessmentModel>(0);
        private Set<StudenthastherapistModel> studenthastherapists = new HashSet<StudenthastherapistModel>(0);

        public StudentModel() {
        }

        public StudentModel(GuardianModel guardian, String studentFname, String studentMname, String studentLname,
                Date studentBirthdate, int studentAge, String studentGender, String studentNationality, String studentProgram) {
            this.guardian = guardian;
            this.studentFname = studentFname;
            this.studentMname = studentMname;
            this.studentLname = studentLname;
            this.studentBirthdate = studentBirthdate;
            this.studentAge = studentAge;
            this.studentGender = studentGender;
            this.studentNationality = studentNationality;
            this.studentProgram = studentProgram;
        }

        public StudentModel(GuardianModel guardian, String studentFname, String studentMname, String studentLname,
                Date studentBirthdate, int studentAge, String studentGender,
                String studentNationality, String studentProgram, Set<AssessmentModel> assessments,
                Set<StudenthastherapistModel> studenthastherapists) {
            this.guardian = guardian;
            this.studentFname = studentFname;
            this.studentMname = studentMname;
            this.studentLname = studentLname;
            this.studentBirthdate = studentBirthdate;
            this.studentAge = studentAge;
            this.studentGender = studentGender;
            this.studentNationality = studentNationality;
            this.studentProgram = studentProgram;
            this.assessments = assessments;
            this.studenthastherapists = studenthastherapists;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

        @Column(name = "student_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Integer getStudentId() {
            return this.studentId;
        }

        public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
            this.studentId = studentId;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "guardian_id", nullable = false)
        public GuardianModel getGuardian() {
            return this.guardian;
        }

        public void setGuardian(GuardianModel guardian) {
            this.guardian = guardian;
        }

        @Column(name = "student_fname", nullable = false, length = 45)
        public String getStudentFname() {
            return this.studentFname;
        }

        public void setStudentFname(String studentFname) {
            this.studentFname = studentFname;
        }

        @Column(name = "student_mname", nullable = false, length = 45)
        public String getStudentMname() {
            return this.studentMname;
        }

        public void setStudentMname(String studentMname) {
            this.studentMname = studentMname;
        }

        @Column(name = "student_lname", nullable = false, length = 45)
        public String getStudentLname() {
            return this.studentLname;
        }

        public void setStudentLname(String studentLname) {
            this.studentLname = studentLname;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name = "student_birthdate", nullable = false, length = 10)
        public Date getStudentBirthdate() {
            return this.studentBirthdate;
        }

        public void setStudentBirthdate(Date studentBirthdate) {
            this.studentBirthdate = studentBirthdate;
        }

        @Column(name = "student_age", nullable = false)
        public int getStudentAge() {
            return this.studentAge;
        }

        public void setStudentAge(int studentAge) {
            this.studentAge = studentAge;
        }

        @Column(name = "student_gender", nullable = false, length = 6)
        public String getStudentGender() {
            return this.studentGender;
        }

        public void setStudentGender(String studentGender) {
            this.studentGender = studentGender;
        }

        @Column(name = "student_nationality", nullable = false, length = 15)
        public String getStudentNationality() {
            return this.studentNationality;
        }

        public void setStudentNationality(String studentNationality) {
            this.studentNationality = studentNationality;
        }

        @Column(name = "student_program", nullable = false, length = 45)
        public String getStudentProgram() {
            return this.studentProgram;
        }

        public void setStudentProgram(String studentProgram) {
            this.studentProgram = studentProgram;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Student")
        public Set<AssessmentModel> getAssessments() {
            return this.assessments;
        }

        public void setAssessments(Set<AssessmentModel> assessments) {
            this.assessments = assessments;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Student")
        public Set<StudenthastherapistModel> getStudenthastherapists() {
            return this.studenthastherapists;
        }

        public void setStudenthastherapists(Set<StudenthastherapistModel> studenthastherapists) {
            this.studenthastherapists = studenthastherapists;
        }

    }
```

And here is the error:

```
            HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    type Exception report
    message javax.servlet.ServletException:   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
    exception 
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

    root cause 
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


    root cause 
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    softdev.asese.utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    softdev.asese.dao.GuardianDao.getGuardian(GuardianDao.java:16)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:93)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



    root cause 
    org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: softdev.asese.models.AssessmentModel.Student in softdev.asese.models.StudentModel.assessments
        org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:769)
        org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:729)
        org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
        softdev.asese.utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
        softdev.asese.dao.GuardianDao.getGuardian(GuardianDao.java:16)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:93)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes seems be ok, except by the upper case of your property Student in AssessmentModel. Try changing to lower case the property name and the mappedBy reference. Also, you can try adding some parameters to your annotations like my example. I'm relatively new with hibernate and know that one simple word in annotations could be important.

In my parent class I have ...

```java
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="cobpresGestion")
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
public Set<CobpresOptionDet> getCobpresOptionDets() {
    return this.cobpresOptionDets;
}
```

In my child class I have ...

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="IDCOBPRES", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
public CobpresGestion getCobpresGestion() {
    return this.cobpresGestion;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the naming and it's now working!

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you what's wrong:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Student")
```

> mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: softdev.asese.models.AssessmentModel.Student in softdev.asese.models.StudentModel.assessments

It should be

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student")
```

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the naming and it's now working!